# when i deploy my fastapi code in heroku im getting the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'"

Tags: python, heroku-api

```
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757492+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757492+00:00 app[web.1]: from . import models
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757499+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./app/models.py", line 6, in <module>
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757499+00:00 app[web.1]: from tkinter import CASCADE
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757507+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757507+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2022-07-21T11:51:29.757523+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
2022-07-21T11:52:28.786261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-21T11:52:28.821355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-21T11:52:28.964472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-21T11:52:29.012344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-21T11:52:29.968060+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fastapi-suseendar.herokuapp.com request_id=d56498df-1334-4f73-be66-c57a1b561a21 fwd="117.195.112.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T11:52:30.295259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fastapi-suseendar.herokuapp.com request_id=991b7d74-07b1-40b2-8996-d7346e7e14d0 fwd="117.195.112.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T12:00:09.627570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fastapi-suseendar.herokuapp.com request_id=b3d7dc78-dda2-46e6-ac49-e0a78d38740d fwd="117.195.112.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T12:00:09.918861+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fastapi-suseendar.herokuapp.com request_id=71597b8a-22d6-4bfc-9893-763c78842fdb fwd="117.195.112.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

i tried to deploy my fastapi api in heroku but shows the error nomoulefounderror ,i'm not sure what is the issue...i have seen some anwers to install tkinter in brew but nothing works.does anyone has idea on what im doing wrong?

Comment: do you use module `tkinter` in your code? When you run `tkitner` on server then it will try to use monitor connected directly to server, and use GUI installed on server. But severs don't use GUI, monitiors and video cards so they don't install `tkinter` because they can't display it. And they don't have method to send `tkinter` output to your local monitor (`tkinter` wasn't created to work remotly - to send output to other computer)

Comment: if you want to run code on server then you CAN'T use `tkitner`, `PyQt` and other GUI frameworks but you have to use web framework and generate results as HTML.